# how to store variadic template functiont pointers in an array an then assign the functions to each pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers, variadic-templates

Suppose I have the following functions:

```
static bool fun1(IOPin* obj) { }
static bool fun2(IOPin* obj, const bool& arg) { }
```

I want to be able to store pointers pointing to each of these functions in an array, something like:

```
template<typename ...Args>
static bool (*callbacks[2])(IOPin*, const Args&...){nullptr};

callbacks[0] = &fun1;
callbacks[1] = &fun2;
```

However, a couple of errors arise:

1 - when assigning "fun1"

```
callbacks[0] = &fun1;
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
 error: missing template arguments before '[' token
```

So, I have the questions: How to explicitly pass "no template arguments". Since no variadic arguments were passed, is it okay to use:

```
callbacks<void>[0] = &fun1;
```

However, doing this, causes the following compile time error:

```
error: forming reference to void
static bool (*callbacks[2])(IOPin *obj, const Args&...){nullptr};
              ^~~~~~~~~
```

2 - Also, if I try to assign "fun2":

```
callbacks<bool>[1] = &fun2;
```

I get the following compile time error:

```
 undefined reference to `callbacks<bool>'
```

What am I missinterpreting or how are my concepts bad here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your template declaration does not do what you think it does. It declares a template for many different `callback`s. Unfortunately C++ does not work the way you need it to work. You'll need to come up with some other, fundamentally different approach.

Comment: Don't use function pointeres. Use `std::vector<std::function<void ()>>`. This also works nicer if you want to call member functions of classes. Just wrap those in a lambda and pass them on. You might need to template the return type though

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is exactly one questioning that was on my head, if it really declared an array for functions pointers or it declared a template for many callbacks.

Thanks

Comment: How do you keep track of the correct parameters to apply for each function in the array ? This array of functions looks a lot like an interface... Wouldn't a class with virtual functions do the job, while keeping everything type-safe?

Comment: Imagine you somehow managed to declare and populate `callbacks` the way you want. How do you plan to use it? How are you going to actually call those functions, and to know which parameters to pass to which callback? Show an example of what you imagine the using code would look like.

Comment: There are no template functions in C++, there are function templates. Templates are not functions. There are no template pointers either, only function pointers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I though that calling it like callback[0](IOPinObj); would accomplish the job and that the compiler would be able to deduce the template

Comment: But `fun2` expects its second `const bool&` parameter. Where would that come from? Do you expect the compiler to somehow magically invent a new `bool` variable, guess what value to assign to it, and pass it to the function? Or do you plan to just hard-code the knowledge that `callback[0]` is to be called with one argument and `callback[1]` with two arguments? In this case, I don't see the point of storing them in an array; just have two separate variables of appropriate types, `callback0` and `callback1`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik note that I wrote callback[0] and thats where fun1 is, which expects only a IOPin object. If I were to call fun2 I would do: callback[1](IOPinObj, trueVar)

Comment: Like I said - if you aren't going to use `callback[0]` and `callback[1]` uniformly (e.g. in a loop over all callbacks), then there's no point trying to store them in an array. Have a separate variable for each callback, with the matching type.

Comment: Nothing forbids an index to be a runtime variable. What code should a compiler generate for `void foo(int i) { IOPin* ptr = /* ... */; callback[i](ptr); }` given that at the runtime `i` could be equal to `1`? If you know the size and the index at the compiletime, you could use `std::tuple` if for some reason two variables are not an option.